# Getting values from react-select component in react-hook-form?

Tags: reactjs, react-select, react-hook-form

I'm trying to use a `react-select` component inside of a form created using `react-hook-form`. I have followed the instructions from the react-hook-form website [here](https://react-hook-form.com/get-started/#IntegratingwithUIlibraries), but when I submit the form the value from the select component is `""` (the default value).

I know that the form is working in general because other values that are input with `ref={register}` work fine. It's just this one value that I'm using the `Controller` for. Am I missing a prop in the `Select` component or am I going wrong somewhere else?

I have a parent component where the form is defined:

```
<Form id="public-share-form" onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
   <Controller
    as={<PublicShareNetworkSelect />}
    name="network"
    control={control}
    defaultValue=""
   />
</Form>
```

Then a child component for the `react-select` component used in the `as` prop of the `Controller`:

```
return (
   <Select
   closeMenuOnSelect={true}
   options={networks}
   noOptionsMessage={() => "No matching options"}
   defaultValue=""
   className="basic-single"
   classNamePrefix="select"
/>
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use `Select` directly like this:

```
<Controller
  as={
    <Select
      closeMenuOnSelect={true}
      options={networks}
      noOptionsMessage={() => "No matching options"}
      defaultValue=""
      className="basic-single"
      classNamePrefix="select"
    />
  }
  name="network"
  control={control}
  defaultValue=""
/>
```

Comment: So essentially I can't have the `Select` be embedded in a child function component?

Comment: yep, not like your code, if you want to do so, I think you need to use `forwardRef` to pass the `ref` down to child `component`

Comment: Thanks...I just moved the `Controller` to the child component to keep everything clean and it works!

Comment: @userNick Cheers